# Call a function when a property gets set on an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't really know how to explain this but I'll show you code and tell you what I'd like to achieve.

Let's say I make a quick object:

```
var test = {};
```

And then I set a property to it: (I **insist** on the syntax, it mustn't use any function as the setter)

```
test.hello = 'world';
```

Pretty simple, eh? Now I'd like to add a function to that object that would get called everytime a new property gets set. Like this:

```
var test = { 
                newPropertyHasBeenSet: function(name){ 
                    console.log(name + 'has been set.'); 
                } 
            };

test.hello = 'world';

// Now newPropertyHasBeenSet gets called with 'hello' as an argument.
// hello has been set.
```

I don't know if it's possible, but that would be quite amazing. Anyone has an idea of how to achieve so?

EDIT: I'd like also to be able to do the same for property get (so `test.hello` would call `get('hello')` for example).

EDIT2: **This is for server-side javascript using node.js**.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: This is possible in Firefox via `Proxy`, and is likely coming to ECMAScript.

Comment: If nobody made new libraries we'd all be using prototype.

Comment: Getters and setters gets you halfway there but what you want would basically involve overloading the . property for a specialized object, which is something we can't do in JS yet.

Comment: Oops. I of course meant the '.' operator, not property.

Comment: There are versions of Mozilla's JavaScript that supoprt [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) but other than that, support is limited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this example in chrome (as mentioned in previous comments it uses [ES6 Proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies)):

```
var p = new Proxy(
    {},
    {
        get: function(obj, name) {
            console.log('read request to ' + name + ' property');
            if (name == 'test_test') return 1234;
            else return 'Meh';
        },
        set: function(obj, name, value) {
            console.log('write request to ' + name + ' property with ' + value + ' value');
        },
    }
);

console.log(p.test_test);
console.log(p.test);
p.qqq = 'test';
```

result:

```
read request to test_test property
1234
read request to test property
Meh
write request to qqq property with test value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tagged my question with node.js but forgot to mention in the question that this was for a server-side application. But still thanks for your answer, this is very interesting.

Comment: above example works unchanged when started from node.js as `node --harmony_proxies`

Comment: OMG. You are amazing. Thanks a LOT. I was looking for ES5 Proxy re-implementations for Node.js and wasn't aware of this flag at all. Thanks!

Comment: it's V8 flag, `node --v8-options` to see full list.

Comment: Getting `Proxy.create is not a function`

Comment: @SanyamJain quite a lot changed in last 7 years, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy for current API

Comment: @SanyamJain I updated example to match latest Proxy api

Answer (score 4):

```
var test = {};

Object.defineProperty(test, "hello", {
    get : function () {
        return this._hello;
    },
    set : function (val) {
        alert(val);
        this._hello = val;
    }
});

test.hello = "world";
```

Something like that. But it will not work on old browsers.

You can find more options here: http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html

Comment: This is nice, but it only sets a watch on "hello". Is there a way to do this for arbitrary properties?

Comment: You can create a property with any name in this way. You can also write a function to wrap existing properties and attach extra actions on getting and setting.

Comment: Surprisingly, it works fine. It does what I want but I'd need it to listen for ANY property instead of a predefined one. This is hard since it's for a node.js server app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you really insist on keeping the `test.hello = "world"` syntax to detect changes **for existing properties**, then you'll have to wait a few years for `Object.watch` to become part of the next EcmaScript standard.

Luckily, you can do the same in EcmaScript 5 using `Object.defineProperty`. [Eli Grey made a nice `Object.watch` polyfill](https://gist.github.com/384583) which you can call like this:

```
var test = {};
test.watch("hello", function(propertyName, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(propertyName + " has been set to " + newValue);
});
test.hello = "world"; // triggers the watch handler
```

You could modify his code to trigger a different handler inside the `getter` as well, so you can detect property accesses.

Unfortunately, [browser support is limited to modern browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) including Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 4, Chrome, Opera 12 and Safari 5.

If you want to trigger a handler when a **new property** is set, you'll have even more trouble. The best you could do is wrapping your object inside a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and placing a `set` trap. You can then detect whether the property already existed by testing if `this.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(name)` returns a 'truthy' value. The Proxy API is very experimental though and only a few browsers provide a prototype implementation to play with. You'll probably have to wait quite a while to get a completed API with decent browser support.

Comment: I think what he wants is some observer to be aware of when any new property label is applied to an object.

Comment: @ErikReppen Hmm, good point. That makes it even harder though, as you need to wrap your object inside a proxy, and that's an experimental API only supported by a few browsers.

Comment: @mattiasbuelens—`Object.watch` is not part of ES5, [defineProperty](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.6) is.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out, apparently we have to wait even longer for `Object.wait`. I've updated my answer to clarify the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tagged my question with 'node.js' but forgot to mention it inside the question itself that it was for a server-side app. But still thanks for the very good answer. The gist you join is interesting though. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomShreds Ah, that explains a lot. It's easier with Node.js of course, since you can use the latest and greatest additions in the V8 engine and go nuts with proxies. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need a library that provides key-value observing and bindings.

[ember-metal is one such library.](http://toolbox.no.de/packages/ember-metal)

basically you create objects, and you can register observers on properties of those objects.

```
var obj = Em.Object.create({
   val: null
   valDidChange:function(){...}.observes('val')
});
```

valDidChange will fire whenever `val` property changes, so

```
obj.set('val', 'newValue');
```

will cause the observer to fire.

Comment: I'd need something a bit smaller, I'm myself developing a framework, so I don't want to include another framework into mine hehe. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @TomShreds if this didn't involve including a framework, would that syntax be acceptable to you? That is, if you could do the same thing yourself, would you be fine with calling `obj.set('val', 'newValue')`?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? [Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/xKDRF/)

```
var objectManager = function(obj, setCallback){
    this.obj = obj;
    this.setCallback = setCallback;
};

objectManager.prototype.setProperty = function(prop, value){
    this.obj[prop] = value;
    this.setCallback(prop);
};

objectManager.prototype.getObj = function(){
    return this.obj;
};

// USAGE:
var testMgr = new objectManager({}, function(prop){
    console.log(name + ' has been set.'); 
});
testMgr.setProperty("hello", "world"); //should log "hello has been set.";
```

Comment: I insist on the syntax: test.hello = 'world'; I don't want to use any kind of function for calling it. Thanks for your answer.