# Vue.js 2: action upon state variable change

Tags: vuejs2

I am using a simple state manager  (NOT vuex) as detailed in [the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html). Simplified, it looks like this:

```
export const stateholder = {
   state: {
      teams: [{id: 1, name:'Dallas Cowboys'}, {id: 2, name:'Chicago Bears'}, {id: 3, name:'Philadelphia Eagles'}, {id:4, name:'L.A. Rams'}],
      selectedTeam: 2,
      players: []
   }
   getPlayerList: async function() { 
      await axios.get(`http://www.someapi.com/api/teams/${selectedTeam}/players`) 
         .then((response) => {
            this.state.players = response.data;
         })
   }
}
```

How can I (reactively, not via the onChange event of an HTML element) ensure `players` gets updated (via `getPlayerList`) every time the `selectedTeam` changes?

Any examples of simple state that goes a little further than the official docs? Thank you.

Comment: You could do what's mentioned in the docs (what happens internally in Vue): convert `selectedTeam` to a getter/setter that triggers `getPlayerList` on `set`. You could also look into using a proxy.

Comment: @chipit24 Thanks, I went through most of the docs but must have missed this pattern. The getter/setter works great with the action on `set`. If you make an answer out of this I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, Vue uses `Object.defineProperty` to convert properties to getter/setter pairs to make them reactive. This is mentioned in the docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked:

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data
> option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them
> to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty.

You can see how this is set up in the Vue source code here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/79cabadeace0e01fb63aa9f220f41193c0ca93af/src/core/observer/index.js#L134.

You could do the same to trigger `getPlayerList` when `selectedTeam` changes:

```
function defineReactive(obj, key) {
  let val = obj[key]

  Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: function reactiveGetter() {
      return val;
    },
    set: function reactiveSetter(newVal) {
      val = newVal;
      stateholder.getPlayerList();
    }
  })
}

defineReactive(stateholder.state, 'selectedTeam');
```

Or you could set it up implicitly using an internal property:

```
const stateholder = {
  state: {
    teams: [/* ... */],
    _selectedTeam: 2,
    get selectedTeam() {
      return this._selectedTeam;
    },
    set selectedTeam(val) {
      this._selectedTeam = val;
      stateholder.getPlayerList();
    },
    players: []
  },
  getPlayerList: async function() {
    /* ... */
  },
};
```

Your question is also similar to [Call a function when a property gets set on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552064/call-a-function-when-a-property-gets-set-on-an-object), and you may find some more information there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `v-on:change` or [@change](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand) for short to trigger `getPlayerList`.

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvshmypg/), simulating the request with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not a "reactive" solution, as it doesn't address when the value of `selectedTeam` changes via Javascript, or from a different user action, etc. There may not be any user-selectable elements at all.

Comment: @ExactaBox I do not understand. This is reactive, since it _reacts_ to the changes of `players`. What is your definition of "reactive"? Besides: If your code is able to change `selectedTeam`, it is able to trigger `getPlayerList`. What's the deal?

Comment: It only triggers when the `select` is changed, which just happens to be connected to `selectedTeam`. So if `selectedTeam` changes via some other way, nothing will happen. The reason I don't believe this is considered reactive (and I could be wrong) is that the `select` is actively triggering an event (via `@change`), it is not the framework "reacting" to the change of the variable's value/state.